# Redirect non-www to www excluding subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

First of all, please don't mark this question as duplicate because I've tried all other answers and no one works for me. I have a subdomain called `account.domain.com` and this is the code in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I want to redirect visits from `domain.com` to `www.domain.com`, this works fine. The problem comes when I access the subdomain `account.subdomain.com` and it redirects to `www.account.subdomain.com/account/.php`... I don't know why.

I've tested a lot of different codes but I get the same result. My site is hosted in a free account in Hostinger.es.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target only main domain then use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I think the other solutions didn't worked at all because I didn't replace "domain.com" with the real domain name ;D